# Looking to retrieve user's groups in SharePoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am running SharePoint Foundation 2010. I have a claims based site setup to use a trusted token provider. I am passing it a set of claims that determine the user's group. They look similar to this: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group. On my SharePoint end I have created some SharePoint groups and users to these SharePoint groups through the claims groups. The permissions are working great and I can manipulate them however.

The issue is I would like to get these users' SharePoint groups from code (preferably jQuery) I have attempted to use the SPServices but haven't had much luck. For some reason I can only obtain the user's group if they have been directly added (not added through their group) I followed this tutorial http://azzu-sheikh.blogspot.com/2013/05/jquery-spservices-to-get-current-user.html and it works well if the user has been directly added.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is a "claim group" ?
With [SharepointPlus and the `isMember` function](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.isMember) I check if the user is a direct member of the Sharepoint group, or if he's part of an active directory group that is itself member of the Sharepoint group.

For example if I'm part of myteam@sharepoint.com and if I add myteam@sharepoint.com to my "Sharepoint Group", then the `isMember` function should return true with `$SP().isMember({user:"john_doe", group:"Sharepoint Group"}, function(isMember) { })`

This function is able to doing that based on [the `distributionLists` function](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.distributionLists) that will find the distribution lists (that I've called "active directory group" above) for the user.

I'm note sure it's what you're looking for ?!

Comment: Thanks. A "claim group" is an AD group passed as a claim from my Secure Token Service. I tried this as well but didn't have any luck. This is pulling different groups than what is displayed in the "check permissions" in the Site Actions -> Site Permissions.